# What happens to Bruce Banner when Hulk loses a tooth?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Age Of Ultron* we witnessed Hulk lose a tooth.

My question is: Has Bruce Banner lost a tooth as well?

Comment: Pretty sure he can grow a new tooth...

Comment: And would the tooth stay Hulk sized or would it shrink down to Banner size?

Comment: A better question would be what would happen if Bruce Banner lost a tooth. Would he grow it back once he became the Hulk again?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Nothing happens to Banner when Hulk loses a tooth. When the Hulk transforms back into Banner, he would not be missing a tooth unless the Hulk reverts back to Bruce Banner immediately (and I mean in seconds) after losing a tooth.

- The Hulk's regenerative powers will replace that tooth in the time it takes for you to read this sentence. If he didn't have such powers, he would not be able to withstand the brutal amounts of damage he suffers in most conflicts. In this image below, the Hulk has 80% of the flesh blasted from his body by Vector. He regrows it in seconds.

[image]

- Damage done to Banner does not necessarily transfer to the Hulk either. Any injury Banner suffers is immediately healed by his transformation into the Hulk. He can even shake off effects such as transmutation into stone or glass. The Grey Gargoyle turns Banner into stone in Incredible Hulk #363. Normal humans converted into stone by the Gargoyle normally DIE!

[image]

- *Banner's transformation into the Hulk is slower but still happens and boy is he pissed.*

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to his hair though. If I remember recently Bruce shaved his head and concurrently the Hulk sported the close cropped look.

Comment: Hair is inconsistently depicted where Hulks are concerned. Perhaps since hair isn't alive it may not be regenerated as easily.

Comment: Just once I'd like to see the Hulk regenerate a random hairstyle like a perm or a mullet. Just once!

Comment: @Monty129: Maybe the Hulk could, if he concentrated on it. But... I think he's too busy being angry.

Comment: Also, remember in *Avengers* when talking to Banner, he tells everyone that he got to a low point and put a 9mm (IIRC) into his brain and woke up as the Hulk ... instantaneous healing from the MCU as well.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yes, and he said that "the other Guy spat it out" or some such!

Comment: I'm a couple years too late here, but you might also wanna specify these examples are from the 616 version of Hulk. With the Ultimate version, Hulk's injuries translate to Banner as well. When he went after Betty in Ultimates and Cap broke his arm, busted out teeth, etc., Banner still had those injuries later while in his cell. In fact, it took him weeks to recover.

Comment: Ultimate Universe is gone. A thing of distant memory perhaps best forgotten. I do remember those events though. Vaguely, as though a glass fogging in the distance...:)

Answer (score 0):

Even with insanely rapid regenerative abilities, I wouldn't think Hulk would regenerate a tooth, seeing as how it's pretty safe to assume that Bruce Banner most likely has all of his adult teeth in his mouth. So why would Hulk grow a tooth back if there is nothing to repair because teeth fall out and that just sucks? I guess his gums would heal instantly. But a tooth? It's not like a chipped tooth would eventually come back to being a full tooth if given time. It just doesn't. So his just wouldn't. Of course I'm speculating since Marvel has yet to publish the The Hulk's orthopedic medical records. But it seems a more logical guess that a regenerative ability would only benefit the body when there's something for the body to regenerate.

Comment: I think you mean "orthodontal" or "dental", not "orthopedic". And a chipped tooth can come back to a full tooth - of course, a visit to the dentist is required :-).